# Flask webapp as user interface for a python module

Tags: python, flask

I have written a python module for extracting archives and processing some data from the extracted files, then optionally deleting the extracted files. Currently I am using it by writing user-code in a separate python script. e.g:

```
import my_module
with my_module.archive("data.rar") as a:
    a.extract()
    a.convert("data.csv", "data.xlxs")
    a.delete(keep="data.xlsx")
```

But for non-programmers to use it, I am trying to create a webapp user-interface for it with flask.

What are the best practices for implementing some communication between the user and the module through a webapp? For example

- how could my module to communicate to the webapp-user that the extraction or the data processing has finished?
- how should the it display the list of extracted files?
- how could the user select a file to be processed or to be deleted?

Basically I need to interleave my library code with some user code and I would like the webapp to generate and execute the user-code and to display the output of the processing module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I sense a close flag coming since this is a broad topic and it's been a while since "best practices" topics were allowed on SO. )

Based on my on faults I'd recommend to:

- implement the backend first, don't waste time on web design if the backend functionality is not crystal clear yet. Read about flask blueprints and create a blueprint for all public calls like list directory, select file, unzip file, etc...  test it out, use `requests`, post stuff, check responses, iterate.
- if you are satisfied with basic functionality, start implementing the frontend. For interactivity you can use the very same api calls via javascript you already tested, use `XMLHttpRequest` (or use jQuery - I am not a big fan of that) for posting stuff. The catch here is that when you post (from the browser), you can [define a callback](https://www.sitepoint.com/callbacks-javascript/), so you may use the flask response to update the interface.
- add some css, eventlisteners to your templates to make it pretty and comfy.

Get ideas from [here](https://healeycodes.com/javascript/python/beginners/webdev/2019/04/11/talking-between-languages.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537254/passing-data-from-javascript-into-flask) and [here](https://www.jitsejan.com/python-and-javascript-in-flask.html) and [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xx-some-javascript-magic) (just googled for some random pages, some seemed on topic for you).

You probably want to read [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-and-setup-building-simple-file-storage-using-vuejs-flask-and-rethinkdb) too.