# Parsing data from JavaScript to mysql in my flask webapp

Tags: javascript, mysql, flask

I want to transfer data from Javascript to mysql via flask, how to do it?
In the below code, I calculate scores from the quiz and i want to post it in mysql database using flask

quiz.js

```
const lastQuestion = questions.length - 1;
let runningQuestion = 0;
let c1=0;
let c2=0;
let c3=0;
let c4=0;
let scorepos=0;
let scoreneg=0;

function storeAnswer(answer){
    if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice1){
        c1++;
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice2){
        c2++;
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice3){
        c3++;
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice4){
        c4++;
    }

    scorepos=c1+c2;
    scoreneg=c3+c4;
    console.log(c1);
    if(runningQuestion < lastQuestion){
        runningQuestion++;
        return renderQuestion();
    }else{
        graphRender(scorepos,scoreneg);
        scoreRender(c1,c2,c3,c4);
        renderAnalysis(scorepos,scoreneg,c1,c2,c3,c4)
        score1.innerHTML = "<p>C1:"+ c1 +"</p>";
        score2.innerHTML = "<p>C2:"+ c2 +"</p>";
        score3.innerHTML = "<p>C3:"+ c3 +"</p>";
        score4.innerHTML = "<p>C4:"+ c4 +"</p>";
    }
}
```

the calculation is done in js, i want to push it into mysql via flask. Node.js cannot be used so is there any other method?

Comment: use flask as API and pass using ajax request.

Comment: i am not familiar with api and ajax, can you help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537254/passing-data-from-javascript-into-flask see this can help you.